# How do I use the input from my box to my function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I created a 16 x 16 grid where I can etch a sketch on that grid. It's working well. Right now, I have to call the function **createGrid(number)** everytime I want to change the size of the grid. I have created a text input boxes as you can see on my code. So instead of having to write it again everytime and refresh the page, I want to be able to use the input from this box to change the size of the grid.

One of the ways that I've tried is by creating a new variable such as:
*let number = inputFromBox.value;*
and then write *createGrid(number)* . But it doesn't work. Is there any way how to make this work ? by using the input from the box ? Please help. Thank you !

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let duplicateOfInput = document.getElementById('duplicateOfInput');
let button = document.getElementById('submit');
let inputFromBox = document.getElementsByClassName('size-box');

button.addEventListener('click', createGrid);

createGrid(16);
draw();

// createGrid(anyNumber);
// draw();

// duplicateOfInput.textContent = `${input}`;

// const rainbow = document.getElementsByClassName('rainbow');
let reset = document.getElementById('clear-button');
reset.addEventListener('click', clearGrid);


function createGrid(number) {
    makeRow(number);
    makeColumn(number);
    draw();
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
    container.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i <numberOfRow; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(row);
        row.classList.add('gridRow');
    }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
    for ( let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        for ( let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
            let column = document.createElement('div');
            rows[j].appendChild(column);
            column.classList.add('gridColumn');
        }   
    }
} 

//adds event listener to all divs with class "column"
//added in global scope to allow drawing on page load
//this refers to the element triggering the mouseover event listener
function draw() {
    let columns = document.getElementsByClassName("gridColumn");
    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        columns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
        }

    function changeColor() {
        let blue = document.getElementById('blue');
        let eraser = document.getElementById('eraser');
        let black = document.getElementById('black');
        let rainbow = document.getElementById('rainbow');

        if (blue.checked) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        } else if (eraser.checked) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'beige';
        } else if (black.checked) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        } else if (rainbow.checked) {
            let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#' + randomColor;
        }
    }
} 

//eraser function loops through all column divs and sets background to "" in DOM
function clearGrid() {
    let columns = document.getElementsByClassName("gridColumn");
    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        columns[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: beige;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

#header-title {
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
 
#setGridSize {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    gap: 12px;
}

#guide {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
    font-family:  Asap, sans-serif;
    color: red;
    font-size: 13px;;
}

.canvas {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:  center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
}

/* .gridColumn {
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid beige;
    margin: -1px 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
} */

.gridColumn {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid beige;
}

.gridRow {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}


.default {
    background: beige;
  }

#button-container {
    margin: 3px;
}

 #clear-button {
    margin: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM Manipulation and Events</title>
    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="header"> Let's sketch ! </h1>
    <div id="setGridSize">
        <p id="header-title"> Grid Size :</p> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Size of Board" class="size-box">
        <span id = "duplicateOfInput"></span>
        <button id="submit" > Submit </button>
    </div>
    <p id="guide"> Enter a number between 2 to 99 </p>

    <div class="canvas">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
      
     <div class="buttons">
    <form id="button-container">  
        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="pen" value="blue-pen"><label for = "blue-pen"> Blue </label>
        <input type="radio"  id="eraser" name="pen" value="eraser"><label for = "eraser" > Eraser </label>
        <input type="radio" id="black" name="pen" value="black-pen"> <label for = "black" > Black </label>
        <input type="radio"id="rainbow" name="pen" value="black-pen"> <label for = "rainbow" > Rainbow </label>
    </form>
    </div>
    <button id = "clear-button" > Clear </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `button.addEventListener('click', () => { createGrid(inputFromBox[0].value); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `let inputFromBox = document.getElementById('size-box');` and with `let number = inputFromBox.value;` you can get the value within the click function.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/muhkuh/pen/poLVNME)

Comment: You should add the relevant code to your answer, not as a link to codepen.

Comment: The relevant code is in the answer. The codepen is just for testing.

Comment: It works ! So I'd have to use the getElementById instead of class and adds a variable for the value from the input inside the createGrid function.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `document.getElementsByClassName`, which is most likely returning an array. Try using `inputFromBox[0].value` or switching to finding it by an ID.

Comment: There is no getElementByClassName

Comment: The result is correctly handled as an array

Comment: I shouldn't be answering before having my coffee, lol. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). It allows you to minimise the amount of code you write because you don't have to create rows and columns separately.

Additionally if you set up some [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) you can hook the value from the input [directly into the stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) to update the dimensions of the grid.

```js
// Cache the elements
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
const input = document.querySelector('.size');

// When the button is clicked call `createGrid`
submit.addEventListener('click', createGrid);

function createGrid() {
  
  // Get the value from the input
  const { value } = input;
  
  // Array to hold the box strings
  const boxes = [];
  
  // Loop to create a grid of boxes - for each
  // box push it into the array
  for (let i = 1; i <= value * value; i++) {
    boxes.push(`<div class="box">${i}</div>`);
  }
  
  // `join` the array and update the innerHTML
  // of the grid element
  grid.innerHTML = boxes.join('');
  
  // Pass the value directly into the spreadsheet.
  // This changes the default `--grid-dimension` to the new value
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--grid-dimension', value);

}
```

```css
:root { --box-width: 30px; --grid-dimension: 13; }
.grid { margin-top: 1em; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-dimension), var(--box-width)); gap: 0.2em; }
.box { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: var(--box-width); width: var(--box-width); background-color: lightgreen; }
.box:hover { background-color: lightblue; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Size of grid" class="size">
<button type="button" class="submit">Create grid</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```